# can i use K-means to predict a possible disease from a dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

the code is below that i wrote to predict the possible diseases using k-Means from a dataset which has 3 parameters , , is this correct?
but this is not giving accurate results like i want.

```
import pandas as pd #importing library for reading dataset
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans #using ML library in python for 
utilizing kmeans


##reading the dataset from csv file and storing in variable called data..
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Hassan Tariq\Disease 
Prediction\DataSet.csv")

##selecting data cols from dataset.
X_Data = data.iloc[:,[1]] #first col as a part of first variable
Y_Data = data.iloc[:,[2,3]] ##second col as a part of second variable
##i have used two cols in second variable because we cannot train kmeans 
on three parameters.


#initializing the model with 3 initial clusters.
model1 = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=3)

#training model on the selected data..
prediction = model1.fit_predict(X_Data,Y_Data)

#printing the clusters prediction from the model.
print("Clustered Dataset: \n",prediction)

#printing the centroids which shows the data behavior in each cluster
print("Centroids of the clusters formed: \n",model1.cluster_centers_)

centeroids_collection = model1.cluster_centers_

#specifying the diseases which can be possible.
disease1 = ['Muscle Twitching','Nausea']
disease2 = ['Eye Irritation', 'Lung Irritation']
disease3 = ['Eye Irritation','Diarrhea']

 #loop for iterating all the data in the dataset to predict the disease..
```

Comment: K-Means is an unsupervised learning algorithm so there is no "y" here (`fit_predict` accepts it only for consistency in the API; it is [ignored](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit_predict)). IMHO you should first look into K-Means more thoroguhly.

Comment: so should I use a supervised learning algorithm ?

Comment: i mean , i have 3 parameters in my dataset Ph, turbidity and Tds,now what i want to do is that if ph>11 tds is 200-300 and turbidty is 400-500 (some disease should be predicted) this is what i actualy want to develope.

Comment: Without additional information about your requirements and the dataset involved here your question cannot be answered, whatever method..

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to hard code number of clusters value, First try to get number of clusters using Elbow method. Once you got number of clusters, try to fit in the model That way you will get more accuracy in your predictions. Sample code to get clusters is below -

`X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)`

## Run local implementation of kmeans Here we tested 3 clusters

`km = Kmeans(n_clusters=3, max_iter=100, random_state = 42)`
km.fit(X_std) centroids = km.centroids`

## labels_ are equivalent to calling fit(x) then predict

`labels_ = km.predict(X_std)`
`labels_`